# Create a PL/SQL Trigger to display the message “NEW EMPLOYEE DETAILS INSERTED”, whenever a new record is inserted into Employee table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

[image: This is the question]

[image: This is my code but gets error]

[image: this the error]

please help me.
Where I am wrong in my code.

Comment: It's saying that EMPLOYEE has no column EMP_ID. Does it? But why are you checking whether it's greater than zero anyway? The requirement is just to display a message whenever a row is inserted, regardless of what values it has.

Comment: I see two problems.  First, where would you want this message displayed?  Just like all PL/SQL,  A trigger operates within the server and has no ability to interact with any display device.  dbms_output does _NOT_ write to a display device.  It writes to a buffer, and when the entire pl/sql block completes and returns control to the client, it is up to the client to decide whether or not to display the contents of the buffer.  Now, think about how many ways a row could potentially get inserted .... how many different clients may do it -- sqlplus, SQL Dev, some app written in another language .

Comment: A lot of homework questions seem to assume "display message" means dbms_output.put_line, and I suppose in a learning environment it probably does. Of course in an actual production environment it does not, but we have to hope that is explained to students later in the course.

Answer (score 1):

Works OK if column (`EMP_ID`) you used in the `WHEN` clause exists. Though, as William commented, *why* would you check it? It can't be `NULL`, that's for sure (as it is a primary key), but - what does it matter if it is positive, 0, or negative?

```
SQL> create table employee
  2    (emp_id    number primary key,
  3     emp_name  varchar2(10),
  4     salary    number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bie
  2    after insert on employee
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    dbms_output.put_line('New employee inserted');
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> insert into employee
  2    (emp_id, emp_name, salary)
  3     values
  4    (1, 'Little', 10);
New employee inserted                       --> here's a message

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger trigger1
after insert on employee
for each row
begin
dbms_output.put_line('NEW EMPLOYEE DETAILS INSERTED');
end;
```

No need to write WHEN, as emp_id is mentioned as Primary Key.
CTS :)